# redirect(); function not working after generating a pdf in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

Here i am generating a pdf using the code
$mpdf->Output('Maintenance_Report.pdf','D');
$mpdf->Output(FILE_PDF ."/Maintenance_Report.pdf",'F');
after that i am  attach this email send to user.
After that page is not redirected to my home page.
But when iam commending "$mpdf->Output('Maintenance_Report.pdf','D');". Then redirection works.

```
 $this->load->library('mpdf');    

         $mpdf = new  mPDF('utf-8','A4','','20',15,10,10,10,10,10);
         $mpdf->useAdobeCJK=true;
        $mpdf->SetAutoFont(AUTOFONT_ALL);
         $mpdf->ignore_invalid_utf8=true;
        $mpdf->AddPage('L');
        $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($PrintInst);
$mpdf->Output('Maintenance_Report.pdf','D');
        $mpdf->Output(FILE_PDF ."/Maintenance_Report.pdf",'F');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $fromemail="developer@thephinixgroup.in";
        $toemail = $this->input->post('mail');
        $subject = "Flat Maintenance Report";
        $this->load->library('email');
        $config=array(
    'charset'=>'utf-8',
    'wordwrap'=> TRUE,
    'mailtype' => 'html'
    );
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->to($toemail);
        $this->email->from($fromemail, "Flat Management");
        $this->email->subject($subject );
        $this->email->message($content);
        $this->email->attach(FILE_PDF."/Maintenance_Report.pdf");
        $mail = $this->email->send();
        //header("Refresh:5;url=".base_url()."flat/dashboard");
        $this->session->set_flashdata('mail', 'Your mail has been sent.');
        redirect("flat/dashboard");
```

Comment: You can either do a redirect, or output content. Doing both won't work or will have unpredictable consequences.

Comment: But when i am discard code for downloading PDF then the redirection works. This is the code that i am commented **$mpdf->Output('Maintenance_Report.pdf','D');**

Comment: you must use only one option between
$mpdf->Output('Maintenance_Report.pdf','D');   
and    
$mpdf->Output(FILE_PDF ."/Maintenance_Report.pdf",'F');

Comment: you can refer this: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=125&searchstring=download

Comment: how can u use output and redirect both together?